# Pop UP alert message from c# page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I need to show a pop up alert when some fileds have got not null values. I Used code piece like below , but not working correctly..Could you pls let me know the corrcet syntax for doing that?

```
    if (txtSearchName.Text != "" || cmbSearchOaO.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbVessel.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchApplicationType.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchHull.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchHazardCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(btApplySearch, btApplySearch, "<script> alert('Inserted successfully');</script>", true);
    }
```

Here btApplySearch is the buttonID used in aspx markup.

Comment: already checked if he gets to this code line via debugger? where did you put your code (whicht event)? btw alerts are not really good for such error-messages, i hate such pop-ups on every site, not depending what kind of

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

```
if (txtSearchName.Text != "" || cmbSearchOaO.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbVessel.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchApplicationType.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchHull.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchHazardCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "")
    {
         RegisterDOMReadyScript("alert message", "alert('Message Here');"); 
    }
```

Hope Its Helpful.

Answer (score 1):

if not using Update panel then use below code

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Msg",alert("Javascript message"), true);

else

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Msg",alert("Javascript message"), true);

Answer (score 0):

try the following code inside the if :

```
if (txtSearchName.Text != "" || cmbSearchOaO.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbVessel.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchApplicationType.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchHull.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "" || cmbSearchHazardCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "")
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "err", "alert('Message you want write');", true);
}
```

**RegisterStartupScript** has 5 parameters we used.
**this**:: referers to the control,
**this.GetType()** is used to get the type of control,
**err** is a string key.
**alert('mesage')** whatever you want to write,
**true**:: do you want to add script block in code or not if yes the **true** otherwise **false**

Hope this will work for you