# how to show pop up message then excecute some line of code in c# like return

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have applied pop up, but its not showing a pop up message. I want to show popup if no record found in the dataset. i have done but popup message not coming.

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, GetConnectionString());
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        if (dt.Rows.Count==0)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page.GetType(), "as", "alert('No Records Found...');", true);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any browser errors? Check your browsers console (Usually F12)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pop UP alert message from c# page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16292839/pop-up-alert-message-from-c-sharp-page)

Comment: error in browser-  Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near '<script language=jav'.

Comment: code looks correct. is the row count zero?? Any java script error in browser console?

Comment: yes im getting error in browser - Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'No records found...3'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (dt.Rows.Count==0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('No Records Found...');</script>");
            return;
        }
```

Comment: sorry, still not coming message..@mainak

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me to show pop up, i was using update panel .

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('No records Found..');", true);
//coding after changes
     SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, GetConnectionString());
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            if (dt.Rows.Count==0)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "clentscript", "alert('No records Found..');", true);
                return;
            }
```